# Underline gap in both side aligned line only using `\ul{}` command

Tags: soul

Ho do I underline gap in both side aligned line like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\textquotedblleft\ul{\mbox{\hspace*{3em}}}\textquotedblright~\uline{\hfill}~\the\year{}~р.\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

but only use `\ul{}` from `soulutf8` package. `\ul{\hfill}` doesn't work.

Comment: I would fill the gap with a `\rule[\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-1pt]{...}{0.4pt)` or so.  You might need to `\smash` it as well.

Comment: please clarify what You need

Comment: I want to find out the way to make `\ul{}` command work like `\uline{\hfill}` does.